# Bash script is throwing the error of "missing operand" when ran

Tags: bash, directory, mkdir, operands

I am new to bash and am attempting to take in 2 arguments,  and Argument 1 is the name of the new directory where the copied file will go. Argument 2 is the file to be copied. Argument 3 is the name of the new file. However, I keep getting the mkdir missing operand error message when running it. Thank you for any help!!

```
    #!/bin/bash
    dir=$1
    oldFile=$2
    newFile=$3
    mkdir $dir
    cp $2 $dir
    cd $dir
    mv $2 $3
```

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the `'` characters at the beginning of each line.  Not required.  If you have that in your original code, remove them as well.  For your error, the only thing I see is that `$dir` is empty, therefore `$1` must be empty as well.  How do you call your script?  Show us how you call the script, and the exact error message.  You can also add `-x` to the first line to see debug mode information.

Comment: Calling it by ~$./copies.sh

Comment: message is: mkdir: missing operand Try 'mkdir --help for more information. cp: missing file operand. Try 'cp --help' for more information. mv: missing file operand

Comment: You must provide it with arguments.  $1, $2 and $3 must be specified.  You should call it like this `./copies.sh directory oldfile newfile`.  If you do not give it the values, it cannot invent what you intend to do.

Comment: Okay, when I call it like that, it gives the error of cp: cannot stat 'oldFile': No such file or directory. mv: cannot stat 'oldFile': No such file or directory.

Comment: Ok, lets start from the beginning.  Your script creates a directory.  Then moves an existing file into it and renames it.  So your arguments must be: **1** the directory name you want.  **2** the name of an existing file you want to copy in the directory.  **3** the new filename.  Don't just copy-paste my comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BRAND NEW, this version covers all cases...

```
#!/bin/bash

# Verify number of arguments
if [[ $# -ne 3 ]]
then
    echo "Missing arguments."
    echo "1: new directory name"
    echo "2: existing file to copy in the directory"
    echo "3: new filename"
    exit 1
fi

# Verify arguments values
dir="$1"
if [[ -d "$dir" ]]
then
    echo "Directory $dir already exists.  Cannot proceed."
    exit 2
fi

oldfile="$2"
if [[ ! -f "$oldfile" ]]
then
    echo "The second arguments must be an existing file.  Cannot procees."
    exit 3
fi

newfile="$3"
# no check to do here.

# Create the directory
mkdir "$dir"
if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: directory $dir could not be created.  Aborting."
    exit 4
else
    echo "INFO: created directory $dir"
fi

# Copy the file into the directory, with the new name
cp "$oldfile" "$dir/$newfile"
if [[ ! -f "$dir/$newfile" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: the existing file ($oldfile) could not be copied and renamed ($newfile)."
    exit 5
else
    echo "INFO: the existing file ($oldfile) was copied and renamed ($newfile) in the $dir directory."
fi
```

This script:

- verifies if the number of arguments is ok
- verifies if the directory already exists
- verifies that the old file does exist
- verifies that the directory creation and copy-rename of the file completed successfully

Remember to:

- always `"` your variables
- always check the status of your script commands, you never know what happens in all cases
- be super prudent with `rm`, `mv`, you can loose things if you have an unexpected behavior.

To call the script:

```
./thescript.bash newdirectory oldfilename newfilename
```

It will give you the files-directory structure:

```
$ ls
oldfile
newdirectory/newfilename
```

Comment: Okay, I am still reading up on bash, so apologies for me not understanding directly. But I think I may have a handle on what you are saying now, so I am going to try it that way. Thanks!

Comment: I believe I have it working, but am unsure how to test it properly. Thank you so much for your explanations and help!

Comment: The tests can be to call it with different scenarios.  **1** with no arguments.  **2** with 1 argument **3** with 2 arguments **4** with 3 arguments **5** with 4 arguments (the fourth one will be ignored.  **5** with an existing directory **6** with a non existing old file.  The idea here is to try all cases where the script should fail, to ensure the validations work.

Comment: i am facing the same problem. When I add ""(double quotes) the error changes to mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory

Comment: When you add double quotes where?  I just ran my code on my linxu, it works well.